# Change html5 input type date format

Tags: html, input

HTML5 input type date shows the format of date as specified in the system. I want to change that for everyone without changing my system date format.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible.**

the `<input type=date...>` will pick up the client system default date format but will always store the value in ISO format (`yyyy-mm-dd`)

#### Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> ... as we mentioned earlier, with a date input, the actual value is always normalized to the format yyyy-mm-dd.
>
> One way around this is to put a pattern attribute on your date input.
> Even though the date input doesn't use it, the text input fallback will.

```
<input type="date" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}">
```

> The best way to deal with dates in forms in a cross-browser way at the moment is to **get the user to enter the day, month, and year in separate controls** (`<select>` elements being popular; see below for an implementation), or to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery date picker.